# Too many open files - KairosDB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cassandra, opentsdb, kairosdb

on running this query:

> { "start_absolute":1359695700000, "end_absolute":1422853200000,
>   "metrics":[{"tags":{"Building_id":["100"]},"name":"meterreadings","group_by":[{"name":"time","group_count":"12","range_size":{"value":"1","unit":"MONTHS"}}],"aggregators":[{"name":"sum","align_sampling":true,"sampling":{"value":"1","unit":"Months"}}]}]}

I am getting the following response:

> 500 {"errors":["Too many open files"]}

Here [this link](http://tech-torch.blogspot.com/2009/07/linux-ubuntu-tomcat-too-many-open-files.html) it is written that increase the size of file-max.

My file-max output is:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
382994
```

it is already very large, do I need to increase its limit

Answer (score 1):

What version are you using? Are you using a lot of grou-by in your queries?
You may need to restart kairosDB as a workaround.

Can you check if you have deleted (ghost) files handles (replace  by kairosDB process ID in the command line below)?

```
ls -l /proc/<PID>/fd | grep kairos_cache | grep -v '(delete)' | wc -l
```

THere was a fix in 0.9.5 for unclosed file handles.
There's a fix pending for next release (1.0.1).

cf. https://github.com/kairosdb/kairosdb/pull/180, https://github.com/kairosdb/kairosdb/issues/132, and https://github.com/kairosdb/kairosdb/issues/175.

Comment: $ ls -l /proc/10186/fd | grep kairos_cache | grep -v '(delete)' | wc -l  
ls: cannot access /proc/10186/fd: No such file or directory
0

Comment: Yes, I am using lots of group-by clauses

Comment: How to get version of KairosDB?

Comment: You may know what package you downloaded and deployed (or you can use the version API endpoint http://[host]:[port]/api/v1/version). Otherwise, if you built by yourself, what version of the source code?  I am not sure that the version API endpoint works if the project has been built with maven, I'll check.

Comment: I got following output for version: {"version": "KairosDB 0.9.4-6.20140730155336"}